Another term for “Matzenbrei”
When I was growing up, one of my favorite breakfasts, which my grandmother (of Ukrainian Jewish descent) and then my father used to make, was matzah brei, essentially scrambled eggs with softened pieces of matzah stirred in and fried. But I don’t recall our family’s ever using that term—or the Yiddish מצה ברײַ. Instead, we invariably called it something that now sounds to me like gefrischte Matze.
As soon as it occurred to me to wonder about the term—and had learned a bit about Germanic languages besides English—I assumed it meant “fried matzah.” But recourse to Wiktionary has just revealed that the German for fry is braten, and the Yiddish is פּרעגלען (preglen). And per Wiktionary, German gefrischt would translate as refined (okay, that part seems reasonable because of the cognates frisch and fresh).
So I guess my question may have two parts:

Is there another name—used beyond my family—for מצה ברײַ?
Is there another verb—in either Yiddish or German—that sounds roughly like gefrischte and might make sense in this context?


You might want to look into this wiktionary entry for פֿרישן.
It seems there is a Yiddish term derived from "auffrischen" (to refresh), with "aufgefrischt" as the past participle.
The examples in that article also list 'gefrishte matse'.
Maybe the idea was to refresh or renew the matse by adding the eggs. One can imagine the "auf-" got lost somewhen.

Ah, an excellent lead.   And maybe the sense of refreshed comes from a practice of making this dish as a (frugal) way to create a palatable dish from over-old, stale, matzah. This would be strongly analogous to the French calling (what we know as) French toast pain perdu, which means literally “lost bread,” to mean that the bread is so stale as to be lost, were it not soaked in the eggy batter and thus saved from inedibility.

Yes, the German kitchen also knows some dishes that 'rescue' old bread by soaking it in eggs (and/or milk) and fry it.

And the Wiktionary page you pointed me at also gives as a derived term, געפֿרישט ברויט, whose own entry defines it as… French toast. :-)
